# What's the second most powerful pro-Israel lobbying group in the West after AIPAC?

Tags: israel, western-world, lobbying

> The American Israel Public Affairs Committee (AIPAC /ˈeɪpæk/ AY-pak)
> is a lobbying group that advocates pro-Israel policies to the
> legislative and executive branches of the United States.[4] One of
> several pro-Israel lobbying organizations in the United States,[5]
> AIPAC states that it has over 100,000 members,[6] 17 regional offices,
> and "a vast pool of donors".[7] Representative Brad Sherman
> (D-California) has called AIPAC "the single most important
> organization in promoting the U.S.-Israel alliance".[8] In addition,
> the organization has been called one of the most powerful lobbying
> groups in the United States.[7]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Israel_Public_Affairs_Committee

What's the second most powerful pro-Israel lobbying group in the West after AIPAC? I couldn't find an article ranking them by money collected, number of lobbyist or similar, so it seems like it's not something you can easily research on the Internet. Figures like GDP per capita or market capitalization are readily available, but for some reason for lobbies it seems like it's difficult to determine how powerful, big they are. By West, I mean North America or Europe.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_lobby_in_the_United_States

Groups seeking to influence a government to better serve Israel's interests should be considered "pro-Israel".

Comment: What counts as pro-Israel? AIPAC is undeniable because it is in their platform, but does, say the U.S. Chamber of Commerce count because they have made [statements in support of Israel](https://www.uschamber.com/international/u-s-chamber-statement-on-hamas-attack-on-israel).

Comment: @Obie2.0 I suppose one should limit to those who have "supporting Israel" as part of its statutes or expressed goals. The Chamber of Commerce (of the USA, I guess) may produce statements of support towards Israel from time to time, but that's not why it was created.

Comment: Assuming we stick with self-identified groups, "in the West" meaning outside of the US?

Comment: FWTW, there's a list in the synopsis of this book https://www.amazon.com/Pro-Israel-Lobby-Europe-Politics-Christian/dp/178453238X but I can't say which gets more funding.

Comment: Only one I have ever heard of is [J-Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_Street) - *stated aim is to promote American leadership to end the Arab–Israeli and Israeli–Palestinian conflicts peacefully and diplomatically*.  $2M revenue to AIPAC's $77M.